# 404 error on creation of notification_key in User Notifications in Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, push-notification, http-status-code-404, google-cloud-messaging

I want to create notification_key for multiple user android devices. I proceed exactly according to guide below, but GCM responses me with 404 –page not found error. Endpoint for User notification should be https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification.
Is this functionality available now? At the top of the article, there is a strange note „To try out this feature, sign up using this form“ . This seems as this functionality is not released yet???

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html

Thanks
Vasek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a trial feature. You have to signup in order to test this feature :

> Sign up to be a trial partner for the latest Google Cloud Messaging features which include bidirectional message streaming, and user notification APIs.

In the signup page you have to specify the GCM Project ID you are using to register to GCM. I assume that once you signup and your signup is approved, you'll be able to use this project ID and its API key to access the new features.